# Rally API & Release Burnup Data

Tags: rally

I'm trying to pull release burnup data from the API. Is that possible? If so, has someone done that, and can share the object + query parameters?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will want to take a look at the ReleaseCumulativeFlowData object.

An example url would be: 
https://trial.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.34/releasecumulativeflowdata?query=(ReleaseObjectID = 12345)

The query string will usually be with the ReleaseObjectID = some Release ID.

You then get back the Cumulative Flow Data results which are a collection for each day with counts by ScheduleState - hope that info helps.

(In Rally > Help > Web Services API Documentation, take a look at Cumulative Flow Data for the fields there)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick! I just need to add CardState="Accepted" to the query to get all accepted points per day. Thanks again!